# How can I show dot files in coc explorer neovim?

Tags: neovim

I'm using coc explorer and want to monitor the dot files which are currently hidden. How can I enable showing them?

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your CocConfig:

```
`"explorer.file.showHiddenFiles":true,`
```